# Guidance on using changing symbology in heatmap

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, heat-map

I am symbolizing a kernel density layer that I made with my points data. Using the same data, I've made several heat maps that show varying results. In my search for an answer, it appears classify and stretch are the most popular.

For reference, I'm using ArcGIS Pro. The key areas to pay attention is the top two corners of the image.

Based on my results, how do I determine which method I should use?

Here are my results:

1. Default Heat Map symbology from the original points data. The two upper corners are visible but not very prominent.
   [image]
2. Kernel Density using the points data. Symbology is set to classify with default Quantile settings (11 classes) and "no colour" for 0 values. The two upper corners are much more prominent and the central hotspot is more exaggerated as well.
   [image]
3. Kernel Density using the points data. Symobology is set to stretch with default settings and "no colour" for 0 values. The two upper corners are visible but not very prominent.
   [image]
4. Kernel Density using the points data. Symbology is set to classify with default Natural Breaks (Jenks) settings (7 classes) and "no colour" for 0 values. Similar to the default heat map.
   [image]